# Is it possible to limit the size of a CIFS/SMB share when mounted?

Tags: linux, redhat, samba, cifs, smbfs

I have one big 5 TB (and growing) CIFS/SMB share stored on HDD (RAID) on one centralized server for main storage (and backup) and plan to use several additional Linux servers (as proxies) where I mount the share and access it from within them. However, each of those servers will have 2 small 1TB SSDs configured in RAID 1 and therefore each of them can hold no more than 1 TB of data. For this reason, I would like to limit the disk space used on each proxy server to e.g. 0.8 TB to cache only the most used files to avoid sending network requests to the storage server every time a file is requested. Would this be possible?

The servers where the share would be mounted will be running AlmaLinux 9.3.